# Need some help installing ubuntu server via usb

Tags: server, usb

I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.1 Server as a iso file and would like to know how i install it via a usb. The Macine im installing it on dosnt have a desk drive.

Comment: what is desk drive? I know about HDD, SSD, CD/DVD and USB flash drives. What exactly your machine does not have?

Comment: CD Drive* my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB drive must be 1Gb size for the server (2 GB for the desktop). The  procedure is simple:
1. Download live ISO image;
2. Copy it into USB drive (either ISO content or image itself; I've used some Live Usb Creator, see link in the page below);
3. Boot from USB drive.
Details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick